# Swift + Storyboards: segue.identifier crash on iPad (iPhone ok)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have a universal iOS 8 app written in Swift that shares a storyboard for all devices. On iPhone it runs fine. However on iPad, it crashes when you try to do a "Show Detail" segue.  Specifically it crashes trying to dereference a nil pointer in my implementation of `prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)` when I check `if segue.identifier == "ShowDetail"`

Any thoughts on why this could happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The segue.identifier appears to be an implicitly unwrapped optional, and if you are trying to test the identifer against a string, and the identifier does not have a name, it will cause a crash.

This would happen if you have two segues, and one has a name and one doesn't. When the one that doesn't have a name is tested, it will crash.

If you give explicit Identifier names to all your segues in the storyboard, it shouldn't happen.

Comment: Aren't implicitly unwrapped properties supposed to be declared something like `var identifier: String!` though? I feel like the declaration changed at some point, but I can't find the change. If it were declared as a standard implicitly unwrapped optional you could test it for nil, but as it stands Swift doesn't think that's appropriate.

Comment: If you put in `var identifier: String!` in a playground and then test its equality with another string, it gives an error. Something declared as an implicitly unwrapped property must have a value before using, and that value can't be nil.

Comment: Right, what I'm saying is that UIStoryboardSegue declares `identifier` as `var identifier: String` (non-optional) instead of `var identifier: String!` which what you're implying it is (and what I think it *should* be). Yet in reality it is still `nil` in some cases, thus the crux of the problem--a nil value in a non-optional property.

Comment: If you look at UIStoryboardSegue's `convenience init(identifier identifier: String?` in the docs, it appears that identifier is indeed an optional. Also, you can legitimately do `let segue:UIStoryboardSegue = UIStoryboardSegue(identifier: str?, source: self, destination: self)`

Comment: I'm now convinced this is an Apple bug. Identifier cannot both be optional and non-optional. :P

Comment: That's the conclusion I came to, @BenLachman. `identifier` should be an optional.